# n-tier object mapping help

Tags: .net, orm, n-tier-architecture, oop

Wondering if my approach is ok or could be improved:

```
Public Class Company  
  private _id as Integer
  private _name as String
  private _location as String

  Public Function LoadMultipleByLocation(Byval searchStr as String) as List(Of Company)
     'sql etc here to build the list
  End Function
End Classs
```

Thoughts on having the object mapping like this?

Comment: Isn't this really Object to Relational Mapping?  "n-tier" isn't really meaningful, is it?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would create an instance of Company, and then use it to return a List of Companies?

Some people do this, but I prefer to seperate my data object into a dumb data container:

```
public class Company : EntityBase
{
     private int _id;
     private string _name;
     private string _location;
}
```

I use a base class (EntityBase) that contains common methods for converting the dumb entity back into a collection of SQLParameters (for persisting), as well as instantiating it from a passed in SQLReader (this gets overridden in each concrete class, to map the reader to the private variables).

I then prefer to use a "Service" class that actually makes the database calls, creates the appropriate entity object, and returns it, I can utilize polymorphism here to reduce code duplication heavily.

Answer (score 0):

@Dan

EntityBase would be a base class that each entity object would inherit, something like:

```
public class EntityBase
{
     public virtual string SaveSproc { get; }

     public virtual void LoadFromReader(SqlReader reader)
     {
     }

     public virtual void Save()
     {
         List<SqlParameters> paramList = = this.CreateParamsList();
         DoSqlStuff(this.SaveSproc, paramList);
     }

     public virtual List<SqlParamenter> CreateParamsList()
     { 
          return new List<SqlParameter>
     }
}

public Company : EntityBase
{

    private string _data;

public override string SaveSproc { get { return "SprocThatSaves"; } }

    public override List<SqlParameter> CreateParamList()
{   
    List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>
    param.Add(new SqlParameter("Data",_data);

    return param;   
}

public override void LoadFromReader(SqlReader reader)
{
    // PsuedoCode
    _data = reader["data"];
}
}
```

Now, your DB tier can get a reader with company data, and do something like:

```
Company = new Company();
Company.LoadFromReader(reader);
```

And elsewhere, to save your data back:

```
Company.Save();
```